# DocuSign ID Check with Embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

Using the REST API, I've been trying to create recipients for embedded signing and still require ID check. I can't seem to get it to work. The embedded signing part works fine but I'm not prompted for the ID check.

I know with embedded signing that user authentication duties can be handled by my app but our business would still like to have signers authenticate with the ID check feature.

So is it even possible to use the ID check feature with embedded signing?

Answer (score 1):

How you specify recipient authentication method when using the DocuSign REST API to Create an Envelope will depend on whether you're:

1) creating an Envelope using a DocuSign Template 
   OR 
2) creating an Envelope by supplying document(s) as part of your Create Envelope API call.

In the first case (creating an Envelope using a DocuSign Template), you can use Composite Templates in your Create Envelope API call to specify ID Check as the form of recipient authentication (even if your template doesn't specify any form of recipient authentication). For example, this request will create an envelope (using a template) that specifies ID Check for an Embedded recipient:

POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

```
{
"emailSubject": "Please sign",
"emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "test@test.com",
                            "name": "Sally Adamson",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "clientUserId": "YOUR_CLIENT_USER_ID_VALUE",
                            "roleName": "Signer 1",
                            "requireIdLookup": "true",
                            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Notice that you must set the **requireIdLookup** property to **true** and set the **idCheckConfigurationName** property to **ID Check $** for the recipient, to specify ID Check as the recipient authentication method.

In the latter case (creating an Envelope by supplying documents as part of your Create Envelope API call), you simply need to set the **requireIdLookup** property to **true** and set the **idCheckConfigurationName** property to **ID Check $** for the recipient.  For example, this recipient structure (when included in the context of a Create Envelope API request) specifies that the recipient will be authenticated via ID Check:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "name": "Bob Adamson",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "tabLabel": "Customer_Signature",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": "100",
                        "yPosition": "100"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug here, but I got this to work by specifying the RDA ID Check in the template recipient authentication settings, then when I reference that template in an Embedded Signing API call it starts out on the ID Check before allowing access to the envelope.

Doing this confirms that you can combine RSA ID Check with Embedded Signing, so that's the answer to that part.  However the fact that I had to set the RSA authentication at the template level in the Console and the *requireIdLookup* property in my requests seems to be ignored makes me think that there's a bug.

I will follow up with DocuSign with regards to that property not having an effect on the envelope, however for now you should be able to get this to work as specified above.  If you sometimes use that template and do NOT want the RSA ID Check for recipients, then you can simply make another template that's exactly the same but add the ID check in, and reference that new template in your API calls and use the first template when you don't want RSA ID Check.

Comment: Bug logged with DocuSign, bug id 30830

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I'm still working in the sandbox which, as I just found out, the ID check does not work. So I won't be able to test this until we move to the production environment. When we do I'll try your suggestion and mark this as the answer.

Comment: That's not true, the ID check DOES work in demo sandbox environment.  I'm able to initiate the process by following the steps described above and saving the ID Check authentication setting at the template level...