# Docusign ID Check feature not working via API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm working an envelope with ID Check, I'm sending the following xml for the recipient.

```
<Recipient>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <UserName>Test Username</UserName>
    <Email>test@email.com</Email>
    <Type>Signer</Type>
    <AccessCode xsi:nil="true"/>
    <IDCheckConfigurationName>ID Check $</IDCheckConfigurationName>
    <CaptiveInfo>
        <ClientUserId>1</ClientUserId>
    </CaptiveInfo>
    <IDCheckInformationInput>
        <AddressInformationInput>
            <AddressInformation>
                <Street1>109 Righter Road</Street1>
                <City>SUCCASUNNA</City>
                <State>NJ</State>
                <Zip>07876</Zip>
            </AddressInformation>
        </AddressInformationInput>
        <DOBInformationInput>
            <DOBInformation>
                <DOB>2000-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
            </DOBInformation>
        </DOBInformationInput>
        <SSN9InformationInput>
            <SSN9Information>
                <SSN9>788888888</SSN9>
            </SSN9Information>
        </SSN9InformationInput>
    </IDCheckInformationInput>
</Recipient>
```

My envelope is created along with the recipient, however the ID Check prompt is not displated, not sure why this is not working.

I did notice that the xml doesn't include the property

```
"requireIdLookup": "true",
```

This property might be required, however I'm setting that property to true in my code (C#). Could this be an API bug?

Additionally, If I manually set the "ID Check $" via the portal the prompt is displayed and the information from "IDCheckInformationInput" is pre-populated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guess would be that ID Check is not enabled for you account.  What type of account are you using here, is this a developer sandbox in the Demo environment, or a production account?  Did you purchase one of the API Plans?

Comment: @Ergin I do not think this is the problem. Because I'm allowed to manually set the ID Check, just not through the API.  This is a developer sandbox.

Comment: Are you using the SOAP API or are you sending an XML payload through REST?

Comment: @Ergin Im using the C# .dll 1.7.2 ..

Comment: Ok that library uses the REST API.  The 1.7.2 version was recently deprecated in favor of the new Swagger code-generated version of the library, which the master now points to.  Your best bet is to upgrade to latest version and try ID Check through there as it should work - that version is more complete than the deprecated library.

Comment: @Ergin Our solution uses the NuGet package, which seems to be v1.7.2 we recently updated this package.  Not sure if the Nugget package hasn't been update or won't. I was using the package DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll I see that there is another one, should we use this one...DocuSign.eSign.dll

Comment: The new package `DocuSign.eSign` is the official DocuSign C# client that DocuSign supports.  This new client is more complete than the previous `v1.7.2` version you were using which is why I recommend upgrading to it.  However please note that the core SDK has changed so you will need to change your code if you upgrade.  Otherwise, if you want to keep using the previous version you have the source code so you can add the ID Check feature yourself...

Comment: @Ergin Thanks, I just looked at the code samples, upgrading to this version will mean significant effort. Will try to modify the source code on the 1.7.2 version.

Thanks,

Comment: @Ergin I changed my code and Im trying to do without the dll, just using the SOAP service reference. I still have the same problem.... then I came accross this answer of yours from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/18625449/1706578

Could this be the problem?

How do you specify the RDA ID Check in the recipient authentication settings?

Comment: @Ergin this is working for me now... however in order to make it work I had to also specify:
     RequireIDLookup = true,
     **RequireIDLookupSpecified = true,**
I'm not sure why or if this is going to cause other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why but this worked for me.

Setting both of these parameters to true did the trick...

```
RequireIDLookup = true, 
RequireIDLookupSpecified = true
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing the solution with the community!  Cheers