# DocuSign ID Check with Embedded signing for documents sent via JAVA SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to achieve ID Check on embedded signing through an envelope sent via Docusign Java SDK. I am able to make it work through remote signing however, I get the following error on embedded signing.

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. The value of AuthenticationMethod is invalid."
}
```

I'm fully aware of another post on the same topic posted in 2013 ([DocuSign ID Check with Embedded signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618734/docusign-id-check-with-embedded-signing)). The difference here is that I'm not using any document templates but sending the documents in the envelope itself. Based on the comments a bug was logged with bug id 30830 but I can't say whether this was resolved.

Also, I have already added the settings that I know that are required for ID Check.

```
signer.setRequireIdLookup("true");
recipientViewRequest.setAuthenticationMethod("ID Check $");
```

Can anyone advise on what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell from your question but from what I gather you might be setting the properties on the wrong request. As you know when creating a remote signing request you can do it through just one API request - [Envelopes: create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create).

For embedded signing you still first create an envelope (with an embedded recipient) but then you need to generate the signing URL by calling [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient).

When setting the ID Check authentication for your recipient you still need to assign this in the first request (ie the create envelope call) so that recipient is configured like so:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "ID Check $",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

THEN, in the request body of the second call you need to set the `authenticationMethod` with the same value and provide the other required params to identify the signer.

Please confirm you are following this flow and if so and still stumped then post the actual JSON that you are sending for your requests and we should be able to determine from there.

Comment: I was missing the second part. Once I did the signing url by setting the authentication method it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Great, can you accept the answer in that case?  Thx